# how to allow xsl document() function to be used in Excel 2010?

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

I have an xml document with an xsl stylesheet that uses the document() function as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="skapa_statisk_import.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<filelist>
<file name="188702109342.xml"/>
<file name="189001019802.xml"/>
<file name="189612115452.xml"/>
</filelist>



<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:import href="formatera_excel.xsl"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
 <Testpersoner>
    <xsl:for-each select="/filelist/file">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@name)/*" />
    </xsl:for-each>
    </Testpersoner>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Testperson">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node"/>
    <xsl:apply-imports/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I need to do is to open the xml file (and apply the stylesheet), but this gives the error "AllowDocumentFunction constraint violated". As I understand, this is a property in MSXML that obviously is set to false.

I cant find any setting in excel to change this property, is there any workaround for this??

Comment: Find your solution **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762664%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**.

Comment: Sorry for beeing a noob here, but how would I set this property? Can I set it globally you mean? I got the impression that the property is set by excel when interfacing MSXML...

Comment: @user1077468: And I am not a specialist in Excel ... Why in the first place do you have to perform the transformation *inside* Excel? It is much cleaner to do this independently of Excel. In case you really *must* do this from Excel (and it is obvious that Excell is setting the property to `false`), can you run from Excell an independent command shell (like `System` in C) and use the msxslexe inside it to perform the transformation? Also, it seems to me that you can run the transformation inside Excell using VBScript and thus  be in full control of the settings.